# How to get all menu items id Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I can get all the items from the actionbar with getItem() but I need to compare their id's with a particular id. How can I do this?

Comment: you can compare inside onOptionsItemSelected using if(item.getItemId == R.id.yourid)

Answer (score 2):

You can get actionBar menu items id by calling `pMenu.getItem();`

You can use changing methods of these menu items by overriding the method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_stats:

        break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I used getItemi() on every element and I have to get their Id-s outside the onOptionsItemSelected() method

Comment: When you say outside, is it within the same class or different one?